# Magento 2 : How affects Enable Single-Store Mode Yes/No?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

I have 1 single website with single store. When I enable Single-Store Mode to Yes/No

Not able to change Product Url.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5929#issuecomment-238170690

[image]

What is actual concept of Single-Store Mode & when it requires to set to Yes?

It saves data in `store_id` to `0` or `1`.

Comment: Were you able to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can find more details http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/stores/store-mode-single.html

But answer is simple: more usability. You have the one store and you don't want to care about store scope and select store every time when you need to change store configuration or check reports.